# why can't i boot from cd rom?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, compact-disc

my xp sp3 o/s system is alread set to boot from cd rom 1st, but once the bootable cd is found

and i get the "Press any key to Load " (or something like that) my keyboard and mouse will not

work until windows begins to load. Any ideas on why and what the fix may be?

Comment: i purchased a regular ps/2 keyboard and was able to boot from cd rom.
phenom thank you for info and suggestion. i plan to do a clean install of windows 7 any dos or don't(s) for me to know about?

Answer (score 1):

Turn "Legacy USB Support" on in your BIOS so that you can use your USB keyboard that early.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are using a USB keyboard.  One solutions is to plug in a keyboard that is not USB.